# Maintaining an automatic internal relational table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several tables which get data automatically from certain logs. For example sake, lets say my table consists of two columns:

```
Country | someData
--------|---------
USA     | 123
Canada  | 4545
Mexico  | 4363
USA     | 3434
...
```

Now I have a lot of repetition in the Country column so it makes sense to use a foreign key with another table for Countries but unfortunately, the way that data in uploaded into the table, I can't achieve that. The program that inserts the data inserts the Country string and I can't change that (such as INSERT INTO table VALUES ('USA',3232))

I was wondering if there was a way for the table to automatically maintain some sort of relation such that it does not store the same string multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: i've never actually done this, so I'm not going to claim it as an answer, but check out INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger - i think you can create a view upon which you can have your program insert to and let the trigger place the foreign keys in the actual tables... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let INSERT TRIGGER do the work.

Scenario A)

Table where data is inserted has 3 columns

```
CountryID INT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(50) NULL,
SomeData VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Uploader do `INSERT INTO MyTable(Country, SameData) VALUES(...)`

Your INSERT TRIGGER has to

- for every row in `inserted` table
- find matching CountryID (foreign key) in another (referenced) table
- `UPDATE` `SET` CountryID with
  matched foreign key
- `UPDATE` `SET Country = NULL` to clean space

Scenario B)

Two tables

Table for uploader

```
Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SomeData VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Target table

```
CountryID INT NOT NULL,
SomeData VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Your INSERT TRIGGER has to

- for every row in `inserted` table
- rewrite it into target table using matched foreign key

Also try above scenarios with `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER` (versus classic AFTER INSERT TRIGGER) so Country column it is not even written down to DB - it's "converted" to CountryID on the fly. In Scenario B table for uploader may be a view in fact (uploader inserts into view and instead of insert trigger do the work). See examples on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch that this follows best practices as I learned about it just now, but the need comes up for me from time to time and I've been wanting to learn this, so here is what I think answers your question using an instead of trigger.

```
create table Country (
     id int primary key not null identity(1,1)
    ,name varchar(10)
)
go

create table Item (
     id int primary key not null identity(1,1)
    ,country_id int references Country(id)
    ,data varchar(100)
)
go

create view ItemView as
select C.name, I.data
from Item I inner join Country C on I.country_id = C.id
go

create trigger tr_Item_IOI on ItemView
instead of insert as begin

    set nocount on

      -- add the country if it does not exist
    if(not exists (select C.id from Country C inner join inserted I on C.name = I.name))
         insert into Country select distinct name from inserted

      -- insert an item using the country id for the inserted country name
    insert into Item (country_id, data)
    select C.id, I.data
    from Country C inner join inserted I on C.name = I.name

end
go

insert into ItemView values 
     ('USA', '123')
    ,('Canada', '4545')
    ,('Mexico', '4363')
    ,('USA', '3434')
go

select * from ItemView
select * from Country
select * from Item
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand this question.  You can have one table of Countries and you can use the text representation as a Key, it doesn't have to be an ID number (int, bigint, etc).  This table will have one instance of each country: USA, Canada, Mexico.

In your relationship you have another table that stores the `someData` which can contain multiple entries for say USA.  The benefit is your countries table could have more columns about the object (in this case the country).

Comment: I understand your suggesstion but the program that uploads the data is very dumb and only inserts the entries as they appear in a log so it will always do something to the extent of INSERT INTO table VALUES ('USA',3232).
I can't change that behaviour. Also, for the record, I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Horatu - that is an implementation detail..its not dumb its doing what it is told to do.  Your process after the insert is to `SELECT DISTINCT...FROM...` from that table and insert into your primary key (one side) table.  It really is simple.  The main table will only have one instance of each country.  So your log file that gets sent to you initially inserts into the Log (many side table) table.  Once it is done your program can then select DISTINCT countries from the Log table and insert them into your one side table, checking if they do not already exist.  INSERT INTO OneSideTable...

Comment: INSERT INTO OneSideTable( CountryID ) SELECT DISTINCT CountryID FROM LogsTable WHERE CountryID NOT IN (SELECT CountryID FROM Country)

Comment: Lets call the table I posted above, TableA. How does your suggestion solve my problem of there being multiple similar strings in the Country column of TableA. Also, for various reasons, I'm unable to change the program that uploads the data so I can't run any queries after the data is uploaded.

Comment: @HOratiu at the end of the day you have two tables.  One is DISTINCT countries the other is the many side (all the logs associated with the country).  You dont have to modify your program you can run an SQL Script, or a job that does this for you.